# Counting upward in column until blank?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column, which will contain a few rows of data, and then a blank cell.

I need a way to count the rows upwards in a column until a blank cell and sum the number using `VBA`. Any ideas?

Comment: I have tried using CurrentRegion however it does not work if there is data next to the cells, I would like to use VBA

Comment: Did you try `xlUp`? EDIT: Would you like to try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking. You say "sum the number" but do not specify if the number you want to sum is the number of rows counted or if you want to sum the value of the cells found.

-Edit-

Give this a try:
This will start at the bottom row and count upward until it finds a blank cell
Once a blank cell is found it will sum the cells between the last blank cell and the current blank cell.

-Edit2-

Added insert to the row under column headers so the first row also gets summed.

```
Sub CountUp()
    Dim TotalRows As Long
    Dim TotalCols As Long
    Dim Col As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long

    Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    TotalRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    TotalCols = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    'Assumes Data you want to sum is in the first column
    Col = 1

    Cells(TotalRows, Col).Select
    For i = TotalRows To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, Col).Value <> "" Then
            n = n + 1
        Else
            Cells(i, Col).Formula = "=SUM(" & Cells(i + 1, Col).Address(False, False) & ":" & Cells(i + n, Col).Address(False, False) & ")"
            n = 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: 1 more thing, is it possible so that it counts the first row as blank? It will not actually be blank but I think it is messing with the script.

Comment: Sure, Do you want it to insert a new row or should it overwrite the data contained in the first row and do you have column headers?

Comment: I have headers yes, ideally it should insert a row

Comment: Alright, I updated the code to insert a row under the column headers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Column F as the Column and it has number. Try the below code.

```
Sub sumAndcount()
    Dim recCount As Long
    Dim recSum As Long

    Range("A65000").Value = "=COUNT(F:F)"
    recCount = Range("A65000").Value

    Range("A65000").Value = "=SUM(F:F)"
    recCount = Range("A65000").Value
End Sub
```