# Implementing voice synthesis into this loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Case "END-BOX"
    EndBox = ActiveCell.Row
    Selection.Offset(-1, 2).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    TotalCols = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    Col = 4
    Cells(EndBox, Col).Select
    For i = EndBox To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, Col).Value <> "" Then
            n = n + 1
        Else
            Cells(i, Col).Value = n
            If Cells(i, Col).Offset(0, -2).Value = "NEW-BOX" Then Cells(i, Col).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            n = 0
        ' Application.Speech.Speak (n)
        End If
    Next

    Range(EndBox).Select
    Selection.Offset(1, -2).Select
```

I would like to work out how to get the final sum number to be read out automatically after the sum is calculated, however this loop is proving me trouble and I do not understand how I would implement this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> n = 0
>
> ' Application.Speech.Speak (n)

You are setting `n` to 0 so you will always get 0.

Put that after `Next` to get the final value of `n`

```
For i = EndBox To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, Col).Value <> "" Then
        n = n + 1
    Else
        Cells(i, Col).Value = n
        If Cells(i, Col).Offset(0, -2).Value = "NEW-BOX" Then Cells(i, Col).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        n = 0
    End If
Next
Application.Speech.Speak (n)
```

Comment: Thank you, every time I do this however, it simply reads out 1.

[Here](http://wikisend.com/download/933106/Stock%20Sheet%20Copy.xls) is my document, The green cells are what need to be read out

Comment: Probably because after n is set as `0` it enters the `if` part and adds `1` to it hence you get that value. Do you know how to step through that code?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve with `n`?

Comment: I am trying to sum the total of the column and colour it green and then read it out

Comment: so `If Cells(i, Col).Offset(0, -2).Value = "NEW-BOX"` then what should be the value of `Cells(i, Col).Value`

Comment: That is the final sum I believe, I think I just need a way to get the sum and pass it to the speech line..

Comment: Sam i am not sure I understand. Can you please explain the code logic to me?

Comment: Here is the original code source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957484/counting-upward-in-column-until-blank , it loops upwards and sums the numbers, and then puts them into the cells.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24852/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-sam-cousins)